# Working with Google Webmaster API

Tags: google-search-console, c#

I'm just start working with Google webmaster API. I have a need to mark a site for removal and found nothing of doing that.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not in the [reference guide](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/docs/2.0/reference), you can't do this action with the API.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that help you, how you can enable google webmaster in your website :

http://www.video-referencement.fr/article-26-tutoriel-sur-les-outils-pour-webmaster-google